# Multiple Where Statements from Loop in Callback Function in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a filter function that returns a list of Exchanges based on the features the user has a selected. Each feature has a unique slug, and the $featureSlugs contains an array of these slugs (strings).

```
$featureSlugs = ['security', 'mobile-app', '2FA'];

$exchanges = Exchange::whereHas('features', function ($q) use ($featureSlugs) {
                    $q->where('slug', $featureSlugs);
                })->get();
```

What's extremely strange is this query works for 1 feature or 2 features, but anything more than 2 it stops working and doesn't filter anymore.

I want the filter to get narrower and narrower, so using multiple where statements for each feature, returning only exchanges that have all the features the user selected. This is the code I'm trying and it's not working, but I think demonstrates what i'm trying to do:

```
$exchanges = Exchange::whereHas('features', function ($q) use ($featureSlugs) {
                    foreach($featureSlugs as $featureSlug)
                    {
                        $q->where('slug', $featureSlug);
                    }
                })->get();
```

How can i put multiple where statements for each featureSlug in the array?

Comment: My recommendation is that you don't do that, better check the slugs beforehand and then use a condition `whereIn('slug', $array_of_slugs)`

Comment: The problem with whereIn is it will return any exchange with at least 1 feature in the list, instead of only exchanges with all 3 features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in this way.

```
$featureSlugs = ['security', 'mobile-app', '2FA'];

$exchanges = Exchange::whereHas('features', function ($query) use ($featureSlugs) {
    $query->distinct()->whereIn('slug', $featureSlugs);
}, '=', count($featureSlugs))->get();
```

Comment: Awesome! This works! This is the cleanest solution I believe.

Comment: Yes, it is and I like it when people mark a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right direction. You just have to use `whereIn` or `orWhere`

```
$exchanges = Exchange::whereHas('features', function ($q) use ($featureSlugs) {
    $q->whereIn('slug', $featureSlugs);

    // This one is not optimal of course
    foreach($featureSlugs as $featureSlug) {
        $q->orWhere('slug', $featureSlug);
    }
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
$featureSlugs = ['security', 'mobile-app', '2FA'];

$exchanges = Exchange::whereHas('features', function ($q) use ($featureSlugs) {
                foreach($featureSlugs as $featureSlug)
                {
                    $q->where('slug', $featureSlug);
                }
            })-with(['features'=> function ($q) use ($featureSlugs) {
                foreach($featureSlugs as $featureSlug)
                {
                    $q->where('slug', $featureSlug);
                }
            }])->get();
```